# How to automatically set the parent object in a child property with autofixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I want to use autofixture to create an object graph where children have a reference to the parent object. For example :

```
class A
{
  public List<B> Children { get; set; }
}

class B
{
  public A Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to make a behavior that handles the recursion, but I don't know how to emit the parent object as the content of the property.

```
public class AutoParentOnRecursionBehavior : ISpecimenBuilderTransformation
{
    public ISpecimenBuilder Transform(ISpecimenBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("builder");

        return new RecursionGuard(builder, new AutoParentOnRecursionHandler());
    }
}

public class AutoParentOnRecursionHandler : IRecursionHandler
{
    public object HandleRecursiveRequest(
        object request,
        IEnumerable<object> recordedRequests)
    {
        object handleRecursiveRequest = recordedRequests.First(x => x.Equals(request));
        return ....
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit :
I am thinking of a generic way, without having to specify the types A and B or even the property Children.
For all properties of a property type that contains the object, set them to the parent object. In other words all properties of a type that trigger the recursion guard set them to the last object in the creation hierarchy.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087788/creating-recursive-tree-with-autofixture

Comment: Would it be possible for you to change the API of your classes? The design proposed here is not only hard for AutoFixture to deal with, but will in general be a perpetual source of pain for you and your team members.

Answer (score 2):

My answer assumes that

1. `B.Parent` should be `null` if you create `B` directly.
2. `B.Parent` should be set to the instance of `A` that contains it, if you create `A`.

This can be achieved with the following rather simple customizations when using [PostProcessorFor](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/96#issuecomment-16933545):

```
fixture.Customize<B>(c => c.Without(x => x.Parent));
fixture.PostProcessorFor<A>(a => { foreach(var b in a.Children) b.Parent = a; });
```

Some asserts to illustrate the result:

```
var b = fixture.Create<B>();
Assert.Null(b.Parent);

var a = fixture.Create<A>();
Assert.True(a.Children.All(b => ReferenceEquals(b.Parent, a)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I could definitely use it but I was thinking of a more generic way, without having to specify the types A and B or even the property Children. For all properties of a property type that contains the object, set them to the parent object. In other words all properties of a type that trigger the recursion guard set them to the last object in the creation hierarchy.

Comment: @hokkos: What about a property that triggers the recursion guard for a property of a type *other* than the last object in the hierarchy? `A.Children(of type B) -> B.Children(of type C) -> c.GrandFather(of type A)`