# Populating a Collection Property of a fixture with autofixture

Tags: autofixture

I have just started using AutoFixture, and i am getting the basics down (from what i can see there is much more to it) but i am having an issue and i am not 100% sure what the best practice is for stuff like this.

I am testing a controller, and part of the process is the action can return one of two views.

- If a category has children - show the category listing view
- If a category does not have children show the product listing view

So i am thinking of a few tests for that behavior, but the fixture data returned would be different.  One would return a count of 0, the other a greater count then zero, so i would like the fixture to help me with that.

I have been looking around, and maybe i have to create a customisation of some sort, but was hoping the basic API could help me here.  I tried this:

```
var category = _fixture.Build<Category>()
    .Do(x => x.SubCategories = _fixture.CreateMany<Category>(3).ToList())
    .Create();

_fakeCategoryService
    .Setup(x => x.GetById(id))
    .Returns(category);
```

This compiles and tests run (and fail), but the sub categories always has a count of 0, so i am thinking my call to Create Many in the do is all wrong (it kinda looks wrong but i am still unsure what it should be replaced with).

**UPDATE: should read the cheat sheet a bit better!**

```
var category = _fixture.Build<Category>()
    .With(x => x.SubCategories, _fixture.CreateMany<Category>(3).ToList())
    .Create();
```

This works, if there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `Build` is correct.

---

If you want to customize the creation algorithm for a **single** `Category` use `Build`:

```
var actual = fixture
    .Build<Category>()
    .With(x => x.SubCategories, 
        fixture.CreateMany<Category>().ToList())
    .Create();

Assert.NotEmpty(actual.SubCategories);
```

If you want to customize the creation algorithm for **all** `Category` instances use  `Customize`:

```
fixture.Customize<Category>(c => c
    .With(x => x.SubCategories,
        fixture.CreateMany<Category>().ToList()));

var actual = fixture.Create<Category>();

Assert.NotEmpty(actual.SubCategories);
```

Answer (score 7):

> was hoping the basic API could help me here

It does help you, if you know how to listen :) AutoFixture was originally build as a tool for Test-Driven Development (TDD), and TDD is all about **feedback**. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP), you should **listen to your tests**. In this case it's saying the same as the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx):

> [DO NOT provide settable collection properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn169389.aspx).

Instead of assigning a list wholesale to a property, consider

- making the collection property read-only, and let clients invoke `Add`, etc.
- taking the collection as a constructor parameter instead of mutating property

In the latter case, AutoFixture will automatically provide a populated collection when it invokes the constructor, although in this particular case, since you have a potentially recursive graph, you may need to [explicitly handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168820/126014).

In the first case, AutoFixture doesn't do anything out of the box, but has an `AddManyTo` extension method, enabling you to fill a collection in a single statement:

```
fixture.AddManyTo(category.SubCategories);
```

Comment: I meant it as i was getting it wrong not the API was wrong :) Thanks for the additional info, i will take a look into it.  I think i saw an  example of the AddManyTo function on your blog!

Comment: Hi Mark, this app is not the biggest so the Category class is the classed used for EF so i don't believe (will have to check again) that you can work it without it being a settable property.  For a pure domain object i get you.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used EF, but I believe you're correct :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this stub with a custom list:

```
var stub = _fixture.Build<Entity>().With(x=> x.field, config).CreateMany().ToList();
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet).